# Setting a concrete date to start the datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am doing a calendar with Jquery Datepicker and I have to set the initial date in '1/1/2013'. That means that the first date that shows the datepicker must be that. I have tried that:

```
 $(function() {
   $('#datepicker').datepicker({minDate: '01/1/2013'})
 });
```

But I dont obtain what I am searching for. I am reading in this page and I found another example:

```
$(function() {
   var date = new Date(); // replace with your date
   $('#datepicker').datepicker().val(date.asString()).trigger('change');
});
```

But it doesnt work.

If anyone can help me, I will be very pleased

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker("setDate", new Date(2013,00,01));
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/YuFVT/1/)

Comment: That works! thank you! But one thing, in the fiddle yo have 2 lines with the datepicker, why?

Comment: First one to initialize the datepicker and the second one to set the `setDate` option.